# SQL Server concatenation not working with plus

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am attempting to concatenate two strings using "+", both these strings derive from a substring which have each been cast to varchar(20) from ntext fields that do not allow nulls.

When I run the code, it only takes the first of the two strings, and ignores the second, so the concatenation is unsuccessful. Any idea what I am doing wrong or missing here?

```
    Select  Top 100
            Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20) As PossFirst,

            Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_04 As nvarchar(20)), 1, (20 - 
                Len(Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)) + 1)) As PossLast, 

            Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20) +
            Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_04 As nvarchar(20)), 1, (20 - 
                Len(Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)) + 1)) As PossLogin

    from    V_WOI_WorkOrder w
```

What I'm getting is the Following:

```
PossFirst   PossLast    PossLogin
----------- ----------- -----------
james       roberts     james
mark        smith       mark
harry       chapman     harry
```

What i should be getting is:

```
PossFirst   PossLast    PossLogin
----------- ----------- -----------
james       roberts     jamesroberts
mark        smith       marksmith
harry       chapman     harrychapman
```

The reason for my len within my substring is that the complete concatenation should not exceed 20 characters long, I'm not finished that part yet, but i think that is irrelevant to the point that the concatenation is failing for me.

[Screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lhFC.png)

Comment: We need db schema, sample data and desire output. You only provide the  last part.

Comment: The schema is dbo and the data is just a list of first and last names for around 300k individuals within the organization. No special characters other than hyphens permitted in the names, but they have each been cast to varchar(20) from ntext fields that do not allow nulls.

Comment: schema mean db structure. And we still need see the data. You should provide a Minimal Complete example.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance Juan Carlos, I'm not clear what you mean by db structure. if you wanting me to run 
        select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'V_WOI_WorkOrder'
I'm afraid the data returned is massive. Once again sorry for my ignorance here

Comment: I have however added an image above of the data returned

Comment: @JodySchoultz Hi there, what Juan means is that we need to see your table structure, how it was created, not the entire table, just the fields that you are using on your select. Something like `table V_WOI_WorkOrder (  WO_Type_Field_02  nvarchar(50), WO_Type_Field_04 integer, ....... etc  )` that will help us to understand why you are not be able to concatenate your fields.

Comment: Hi Jorge, Jaun,
These two fields are the only ones I'm using and they are both as follows:
WO_Type_Field_02 (ntext, not null)
WO_Type_Field_04 (ntext, not null)

Comment: Beside the structure I want see the data inside the field. Your result show `james` but what was your original value before substring.

Comment: The original value is james, the case of the substring is to determine if there is a name over 20 characters long. I haven't encountered one yet, but given some of the asian names it is possible, hence catering for it, and in that case i'd have to trim it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure about the issue yet, but we can try doing this ..

```
SELECT PossFirst, PossLast, ISNULL(PossFirst,'') + ISNULL(PossLast,'') AS PossLogin FROM (
       Select
            Convert(nvarchar(20),Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)) As PossFirst,
            Convert(nvarchar(20),Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_04 As nvarchar(20)), 1, (20 - 
                Len(Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)) + 1))) As PossLast, 
    from V_WOI_WorkOrder w
   ) AS T
```

**EDIT :** This is wierd, I have this table

[image]

and tried this

```
select PossFirst, PossLast, PossFirst + PossLast from (
select
    Substring(Cast(w.firstname As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20) As PossFirst
    , Substring(Cast(w.lastname As nvarchar(20)), 1, (20 - 
                Len(Substring(Cast(w.lastname As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)) + 1)) As PossLast
    from nTextDataTypeTest w
) AS T
```

with this result...

[image]

I wonder with what column data types you have, and I wonder what SQL version you're using..

**EDIT :** Lets try trimming them..

```
SELECT PossFirst, PossLast, ISNULL(PossFirst,'') + ISNULL(PossLast,'') AS PossLogin FROM (
           Select
                Rtrim(Ltrim(Convert(nvarchar(20),Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)))) As PossFirst,
                Rtrim(Ltrim(Convert(nvarchar(20),Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_04 As nvarchar(20)), 1, (20 - 
                    Len(Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)) + 1))))) As PossLast, 
        from V_WOI_WorkOrder w
       ) AS T
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this, but i'm still getting the same result where the second string is not concatenating onto the first. It's weird, it's the first time i've seen this happen and haven't had issues in the past with concatenation. I get the sense it may be because the original fields are ntext

Comment: Thanks Ken, That too has not worked. Cheers for your edits though.

Comment: can we extend this a little bit, can we see your table structure?

Comment: Here's what I have on those fields:
    COLUMN_NAME - DATA_TYPE - IS_NULLABLE - CHARACTER_SET_NAME - COLLATION_NAME
    WO_Type_Field_02 [ntext] NOT NULL, UNICODE - Latin1_General_CI_AS
    WO_Type_Field_04 [ntext] NOT NULL, UNICODE - Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Also, i'm running SQL Server Management Studio 2008 r2, and it's on a 2008 Database

Comment: hey jody, would you mind using my latest edit? it seems we haven't tried trimming the fields..

Comment: Thanks Ken, same again sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your ntext fields  contain whitespace. These hidden characters are eating into your 20 character limit.

There are two easy ways to spot whitespace. You an use the LEN function and/or concatenate a leading and trailing character.

I've created an example on stack data exchange (link and code below) using a table variable.  The benefit of this approach is we can all share the same code.

In this example james is postfixed with a number of blank spaces.  The other records are not.  As you can see james is returned without a surname.  The others are not.  This happens because the spaces count towards the 20 character limit.  Using RTRIM will remove these.

RTRIM in SQL Server only works on spaces. If your whitespace is made from other control characters you will need a different approach.

I've replaced the SUBSTRINGs with a LEFT, which will achieve the same result in fewer steps.

**EDIT 1: To include description of original problem and solution.**

**EDIT 2: Answer rewritten after the OPs issue was solved. New answer better explains the issue and solution.**

[Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/403835/ntext-concatenate-example)

```
/* Let's make a variable that we can all share.
 */
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE
   (
      FirstName    NTEXT    NOT NULL,
      LastName    NTEXT    NOT NULL
   )
;
   

/* Populate the table with sample values for us
 * to experiment with.
 * Postfix james with blank spaces.
 */
INSERT INTO @SampleData
   (
      FirstName,
      LastName
   )
VALUES
   ('james                         ', 'roberts'),
   ('mark', 'smith'),
   ('harry', 'chapman')
;
   

/* CAST and CONCATENATE the NTEXT fields.
 * SUBSTRING replaced with LEFT for simplicity.
 * Pipe added to end of each string to show its length.
 */
SELECT
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   LEFT(CAST(FirstName AS NVARCHAR(20)) + CAST(LastName AS NVARCHAR(20)), 20) + '|'             AS FirstLastName_NoTRIM,
    LEFT(RTRIM(CAST(FirstName AS NVARCHAR(20))) + RTRIM(CAST(LastName AS NVARCHAR(20))), 20) + '|'  AS FirstLastName_WithTRIM
FROM
   @SampleData
;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've ran this as well as the other submissions and if i run them against a field that originated of type nvarchar or varchar the concatenation occurs and these work successfully. In turn when I run any of these against fields that have derived from ntext, they only produce the FirstName and fail to concatenate the LastName... I've tested this against multiple ntext fields from the database to make sure i'm covering all options. I also as you said checked for any leading or trailing spaces and there are none. Really struggling with this one, it's strange.

Comment: When you ran this what did you see for the first record james?  The column FirstLastName_NoTRIM should have displayed just ames, while FirstLastName_WithTRIM should contain jamesroberts.

Comment: Would also recommend you try SELECT Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)) + '*'.  The star at the end will visually highlight any spaces/special characters.  Finally you should also try SELECT LEN(CAST(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20))).  If this returns 20 there is some form of white space present, after the name.

Comment: You were right, We have a solution that has worked. Effectively len on the field yielded 1 extra character than were visible. If I then trim off the len as follows: 
Cast(SUBSTRING(w.WO_Type_Field_02,1,(Len(w.WO_Type_Field_02)-1)) As varchar(20)) As PossFirst
It produces a result that allows for concatenation. anything i concatenate to this works. Thank you! How do you want me to finish this off to highlight the answer for anyone else encountering this?

Comment: Thank you so much! Merry Christmas to you too

Comment: Does this mean, the spaces where in the beginning not at the end?

Comment: @JodySchoultz Good question. On its own my answer isn't quite right. Perhaps you could up vote the comment that got you over the line? Later today I'll edit my answer for the benefit of those who come next.

Comment: @KenLacoste they were at the end, however they weren't seen as spaces. a charindex for a space returned 0 however when i coppied and pasted the data into excel it showed a space at the end. my only way round this was to substring on a len-1 which just trimmed 1 character off the end. As all my fields were like this, the approach was OK to use, however if only some of them where like this, i'd need to investigate depper to get the CHAR() on the last character to use it in a charindex. not easy!

Answer (score 0):

Weather using nText, or a varchar field that has originally derived from an nText field, a visual count on the characters differed from a Len on the characters by a total of 1 character.

A visual count on the characters showed for example 12 characters. A len on the [field] showed 13 characters, so when I substring [field] to len[field]-1 as shown below, I am then able to concatenate to it.

```
    SUBSTRING([Field], 1, (Len([Field]) - 1)
```

What we have done is trimmed off the trailing hidden/special character that is stopping our concatenation from working.

```
    CAST(SUBSTRING([Field], 1, (Len([Field]) - 1) As varchar(20))
```

We then Cast our result to varchar, in order to match the other other fields that we wish to concatenate.

I now have my final code using my fields and tables below which works successfully!

```
    Select  Cast(SUBSTRING(w.WO_Type_Field_02,1,(Len(w.WO_Type_Field_02)-1)) As varchar(20)) As PossFirst,
            Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_04 As nvarchar(20)), 1, (20 - 
                Len(Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)) + 1)) As PossLast,
            Cast(SUBSTRING(w.WO_Type_Field_02,1,(Len(w.WO_Type_Field_02)-1)) As varchar(20)) + '.' +
            Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_04 As nvarchar(20)), 1, (20 - 
                Len(Substring(Cast(w.WO_Type_Field_02 As nvarchar(20)), 1, 20)) + 1)) As PossLogin  
    from    V_WOI_WorkOrder w
```